# Field to accept only 5 integers & 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to add a restriction to the weight field to accept only 5 integers & 2 decimals. I have tried below regex but facing issue with the same.

```
/^(\d{1,5})(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Field should not accept 6th integer.

#### Code:

```html
Enter weight:
<input type="text" id="weight" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var regexp = /^(\d{1,5})(.\d{1,2})?$/g;
    var result = x.match(regexp);
    alert(result);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you also share where you using this code

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I am trying to use it in a function which I am calling on onKeyUp   event.

Comment: Please share necessary details in question so you get better solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Explanation:

- Keep a variable `previousValue` to hold last correct value. By default, it will be blank.
- Validate input value. If value is incorrect, stop event and set previousValue as input's value.
- On valid input, set current value as previous value.

#### Validation conditions:

- Input must have numbers(`0-9`) and Decimal(`.`);
- Integer part can have max of `5` numbers
- Decimal part can have max of `2` numbers

```js
var previousValue = "";
function myFunction(event) {
  this.value = this.value || "";
  if(validateInput(this.value)){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.value = previousValue;
  }
  else{
    previousValue = this.value
  }
}

function validateInput(value){
  var regex = /^[0-9.]*$/;
  var valid = regex.test(value);
  var parts = value.split(".");
  return ( !valid || 
            parts.length > 2 || 
            parts[0].length > 5 || 
            (parts[1] && parts[1].length > 2)
          )
}

function registerEvents(){
  document.getElementById('weight').addEventListener('keyup', myFunction)
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
Enter weight:
<input type="tel" id="weight" maxlength="8">
```

#### Pointers:

- If you have defined max possible length, use `maxlength` on input to restrict users.
- Its better to attach event using `addEventListener` than adding it in HTML.
- Its also better to separate validation and processing logic. Keeps you code clean and maintainable.
- Instead of using `type="text"`, use `type="tel"`. This is a minor optimisation for mobiles. It will open number keyboard instead.

Comment: Rajesh, Thanks for the solution. It works, was facing issue with backspace but by checking the key code we can avoid that. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell what was that issue? I mean steps to reproduce. Also, I have added explanation and pointers. Hope it helps

Comment: If I try to select multiple character & try to delete or use backspace it doesn't work that is the field is not clearing. Also if we try to use backspace after just 1 integer entered, it  doesn't clear the field